# How to add MySQL connection file to check the database connection ?

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

so I have a php file called db.php which will be called in the web page :

```
<?php
define("EZSQL_DB_USER", 'xxxxx_xxxx');
define("EZSQL_DB_PASSWORD", 'xxxxxxx');
define("EZSQL_DB_NAME", 'xxxx_xxxx');
define("EZSQL_DB_HOST", 'localhost');
if (!function_exists('gettext')) {
function _($s) {return $s;}
}
?>
```

but on my website I want to check if the db is up and running:

```
<?php
$mysqlConnection = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);
if (!$mysqlConnection)
{
  echo "Please try later.";
}
else
{
mysql_select_db($database, $mysqlConnection);
}
?>
```

I dont know were to place the variables and what variables to change....

thanks

Comment: Could you be more specific. What variables, and what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the following:

```
<?php
$mysqlConnection = mysql_connect(EZSQL_DB_HOST, EZSQL_DB_USER, EZSQL_DB_PASSWORD);
if (!$mysqlConnection)
{
  echo "Please try later.";
}
else
{
mysql_select_db(EZSQL_DB_NAME, $mysqlConnection);
}
?>
```

The variables in the connection string have been replaced with the constants you define using the define function.